# How to achieve async routing with app-router in polymer application?

Tags: polymer

I need to check if the user is logged in prior to rendering the route's import - so async. I know flatiron-director supports this but how would it be achieved with app-router (https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router)?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more clear, you can also provide us with some code that you want to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [issue](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router/issues/95), it might be helpful